# Maven Toolchain config for jdk17 not pickedup by surefire plugin 3.0.0.M7

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, toolchain

Trying to use maven toolchains to compile a Java 17 project while my active jdk is JDK8. I set up my toolchains so they use JDK17 to compile it, and this compilation fails while running tests with  error:

```
Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test failed: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: my/source/ControllerTest has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.
```

My pom tooLchain config fr compiler and surefire plugin(version M7):

```
    <properties>
           .....
           <toolchain>17</toolchain>
            <vendor>oracle</vendor>
        </properties>
  ....
....

<plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdkToolchain>
                                <version>${toolchain}</version>
                                <vendor>${vendor}</vendor>
                            </jdkToolchain>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                         <configuration>
                        <jdkToolchain>
                                <version>${toolchain}</version>
                                <vendor>${vendor}</vendor>
                        </jdkToolchain>
                    </configuration>                       
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>                         
                            <jdkToolchain>
                                <version>${toolchain}</version>
                                <vendor>${vendor}</vendor>
                            </jdkToolchain>                    
                            <argLine>@{surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>                       
                            
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/**Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                           
                        </config>
```

why isn't my toolchain config getting picked up by surefire. Compilation itself is fine, but surefire test phase fails. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get toolchains working if i trigger tests with "mvn test" on surefire plugin 2.22. It doesn't pick up the toolchains though if the tests are triggered with surefire:test.

I have been trying to make it work on surefire 3 but i keep running into the same issue that you posted about. Please let me know as well if you found a way to make this work with surefire 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `forkCount` option, it seems to break the toolchain lookup.

There are a few issues about that in the issue tracker: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-720?jql=text%20~%20%22forkCount%20toolchain%22](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-720?jql=text%20%7E%20%22forkCount%20toolchain%22)

Comment: I actually found removing the <reuseForks>false</reuseForks> made it work.